# VueJs doesn't update data

Tags: vue.js

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="res in results" >
      <td>  <input :id=res.id :value=res.LinkTitle >  </td>
      <td> <input :id=res.id :value=res.URL > </td> 

    </tr>
  </table>
  <button @click="showData">Show Data</button>

</div>

<script>
  const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created: function()
    {
      this.loadData();
    },
    data: {
      results: [
        {id:"1",LinkTitle:"title1",URL:"url1"},
        {id:"2",LinkTitle:"title2",URL:"url2"}
      ]

    },
    methods:{
      showData()
      {
        alert(this.results[0].URL);
      }
    }

  });
</script>
```

I change the url1 to url566 then I click show button and it shows me the old value.
What's wrong with this. Is not Vue supposed to update data auttomatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use the v-model directive to create **two-way** data bindings on
> form input, textarea, and select elements.
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

`v-model` example:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="app">
  <table>
<tr v-for="res in results" >
  <td><input v-model="res.LinkTitle" :id="res.id">  </td>
  <td> <input v-model="res.URL" :id="res.id"> </td> 
</tr>
  </table>
  <button @click="showData">Show Data</button>
  <br>
{{results}}
</div>

<script>
  const vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
created: function()
{
  this.loadData();
},
data: {
  results: [
    {id:"1",LinkTitle:"title1",URL:"url1"},
    {id:"2",LinkTitle:"title2",URL:"url2"}
  ]

},
methods:{
  showData()
  {
    alert(this.results[0].URL);
  }
}

  });
</script>
```